# How to see the prophet (May Allah's blessings and peace be upon Him)?

Tags: source-identification, prophet-muhammad, dream

The Prophet (May Allah's blessings and peace be upon Him):

> مَنْ رَآنِي فِي الْمَنَامِ فَقَدْ رَآنِي فَإِنَّ الشَّيْطَانَ لا
>   يَتَمَثَّلُ بِي
>
> The one that has seen me in one's dream, has really seen me, as the
>   shaytaan cannot impersonate me

[Ashama'il](http://sunnah.com/shamail/56/1)

So, is there any ***Authentic*** Hadith mentioning how we can get to see Him (May Allah's blessings and peace be upon Him)?

Comment: Take a look at the "keys to paradise" (Mafatih ul-Janan) book for such instructions based on Shia Ahadeeth. You can dream any prophet or imam, your parents or anything that you wish, although the way to do this is not really very easy. I couldn't find an English version of the book online to put its link here, but you can benefit a translator to read [here](http://www.aviny.com/Mafatih/Motoon/Mafatih123.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

*There is no way prescribed in sharee’ah for the one who wants to see the Prophet (PBUH) in a dream*

---

> The Muslim who is following the Sunnah sees the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) in his heart; the more he follows him the more he will see him. So when he goes out of his house or goes to the mosque or does wudoo’, he remembers what the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) used to do. When he prays or performs Hajj he follows his Sunnah. When he buys and sells or interacts with people, he acts according to the teachings of his Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him). When he is at home with his family and children he follows the teachings of his Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him).
>
> This is what the Muslim should seek and strive to achieve.

From the Question, "[He wants to see the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) in a dream](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/14052)"

Answer (score 0):

I currently don't have the proper reference but one might have see Prophet Muhammed(P.B.U.H) in dream, if he sends Durood upon the Holy Prophet(P.B.U.H) abundantly and follows his ways with love and eagerness.

[More info about dream and interpretation](http://www.inter-islam.org/faith/dreams.htm).